# Import psql dump without change in pg_hba.conf?

Tags: linux, import, psql

For some time I've been working on an install script for Tryton ERP on Linux systems. Meanwhile, most things are working, but I do not get around one challenge:

I need to provide the option to import a database template which contains several settings to make access to Tryton easier. Using this command:

```
psql -U $db_user -d $db_version < *.sql
```

works, but I first have to change in pg_hba.conf the line

```
local   all all peer
```

to

```
local   all all trust
```

or similar.

Does any method exist to carry out such a command without this change in `pg_hba.conf`? - The install script runs with sudo privileges, so I'm looking for a command powerful enough to ignore restrictions set in `pg_hba.conf`.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Tryton forum,](https://discuss.tryton.org/t/how-to-properly-import-a-database/6748) I got the solution:

> Add -h localhost to the command so no changes are needed in the
> pg_hba.conf:

`psql -U DB_user -d database_name -h localhost < DB_dump_name.sql`

Special thanks to Eddy! (:

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import the dump as a (PostgreSQL) superuser.
When a PostgreSQL cluster is created, a PostgreSQL (super)user is created for the user who will run the database cluster. On Debian systems, a `postgres` system user in created to run the PostgreSQL cluster(s). By default, no PostgreSQL user is created for the `root` system user.

With the standard line in `pg_hba.conf`

```
local all all peer
```

the `root` system user is only allowed to access an hypothetical `root` PostgreSQL account. If this account does not exist, then you cannot connect when running `psql` as `root`.

If you replace that line with

```
local all all trust
```

then **any** local user may connect as **any** PostgreSQL user, which is certainly undesirable. But that allows you to run `psql` as the `root` system user and as the `$db_user` PostgreSQL user.

The right solution to your problem is not to modify that default configuration in `pg_hba.conf` and to import your dump with a command like

```
sudo -u postgres -- psql -d $db_version < *.sql
```

Your dumps should have the commands needed to set the database objects owner to the `$db_user` PostgreSQL user.

The `--` part separate the command that `sudo` will run from the options. I added it to ensure it will not try to interpret the `-d $db_version`. Not sure whether it is needed.

Comment: Unluckily, another problem occurred:

Comment: @herrdeh Are you sure the database was clean before you start the importation? How were your `*.sql` files generated? Are you sure they are not redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily, another problem occurred:

When registering the database with the Tryton install (trytond-admin command), this error message appears:

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "ir_configuration_id_seq" already exists
```

This problem does not occur when I carry out the import with my own ("me") database user (which would require alteration of pg_hba.conf). My guess is that running the psql command with "postgres" privileges, but for "me"-database-user would solve the problem. Can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance, Wolf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).